# Regex that gets the last set of numbers from a string

Tags: c#, regex

```
"abc_d1.txt" should get 0
"abc_d1_2.txt" should get 2
"abc_d1_14.txt" should get 14
"abc_d12_x2_156.txt" should get 156
```

This is what I've done so far, but I am not getting the right result.

```
  string y = "tester_yg1.txt";
  string pattern = @"(\d+)(?!.*\d)";
  Regex rg = new Regex(pattern);
  var z = rg.Match(fullFileName).Value;
  Console.WriteLine($"z is {z}");
```

Comment: "abc_d1.txt" should get 0 - Regex can't match a character not found in the string! You will have to make a conversion from an empty match to 0.

Comment: @PoulBak Yes i think so too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this regex:

```
@"(?<=_)\d+(?=\.\w+)|(?<!_\d+)(?=\.\w+)"
```

**Explanation**:

`(?<=_)` look behind for an underscore

`\d+` match one or more digits

`(?=\.\w+)` look ahead for a dot followed by one more word characters (the extension)

`|` OR

`(?<!_\d+)` look behind for NOT an underscore followed by one or more digits

`(?=\.\w+)` look ahead for a dot followed by one more word characters (the extension)

The last part will return an empty match when there's no digit.

Then you will have to convert the empty match to `0` in code.

**Update**:

To remove the number, you can use this `Regex`, now call `Replace` instead:

```
string pattern1 =  @"_\d+(?=\.\w+)|(?<!_\d+)(?=\.\w+)";
Regex rg1 = new Regex(pattern1);
var z = rg1.Replace(y, "");
string z1  = Path.GetFilename(z);
```

Now z1 should contain the filename with number and extension removed. When there's no number, it will return the filename without extension.

Comment: Thanks. can i add an additional question if you dont mind? in example: "abc_d1_14.txt" how can i get the opposite? result should be "abc_d1" and on ""abc_d12_x2_156.txt" result should be ""abc_d12_x2"

Answer (score 1):

Another option is to use a single set of positive lookarounds

```
(?<=_[^\W\d_]\d+_?)\d*(?=\.\w+$)
```

**Explanation**

- `(?<=` Positive lookbehind, assert what is directly to the left is

  - `_[^\W\d_]\d+_?` Match `_`, a  word char except digits or _ and 1+ digits followed by an optional `_`
- `)` Close lookbehind
- `\d*` Match 0+ digits (to also get the position when there is no digit)
- `(?=` Positive lookahead, assert what is directly to the right is

  - `\.\w+$` Match a `.` and 1+ word characters till the end of string
- `)` Close lookahead

[.NET regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28%3f%3c%3d_%5b%5e%5cW%5cd_%5d%5cd%2b_%3f%29%5cd*%28%3f%3d%5c.%5cw%2b%5cr%3f%24%29&i=abc_d1.txt%0d%0aabc_d1_2.txt%0d%0aabc_d1_14.txt%0d%0aabc_d12_x2_156.txt&o=m)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Use

```cs
(?<![^\W_])\d+(?=\.\w+$)
```

See [proof](https://regex101.com/r/VzYnZG/1)

**Explanation**

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (?<!                     look behind to see if there is not:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [^\W_]                   any character except: non-word
                             characters (all but a-z, A-Z, 0-9, _),
                             '_'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of look-behind
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \d+                      digits (0-9) (1 or more times (matching
                           the most amount possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (?=                      look ahead to see if there is:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    \.                       '.'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    \w+                      word characters (a-z, A-Z, 0-9, _) (1 or
                             more times (matching the most amount
                             possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    $                        before an optional \n, and the end of
                             the string
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of look-ahead
```

Answer (score 0):

if using .NET why not just use the Regex \d+ and do regex.Matches(..).LastOrDefault();